# jackson-dataformat-csv does not ignore unknown properties

Tags: csv, kotlin, jackson-dataformat-csv

Trying to parse .csv file with jackson-dataformat-csv. File contains a lot of columns not relevant for my program.

Tried to use `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on my data class,
and `csvMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)`, but neither works, and application throws exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.RuntimeJsonMappingException: Too many entries: expected at most 2 (value #2 (17 chars) "policy_issue_date")
 at [Source: (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader); line: 1, column: 37]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.next(MappingIterator.java:194)
    at pl.polins.readers.oc.OcPolicyCsvReader.readNext(OcPolicyCsvReader.kt:25)
    at pl.polins.readers.oc.OcPolicyCsvReaderTest.should read PolicyCsv from .csv file(OcPolicyCsvReaderTest.groovy:19)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMappingException: Too many entries: expected at most 2 (value #2 (17 chars) "policy_issue_date")
 at [Source: (com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader); line: 1, column: 37]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMappingException.from(CsvMappingException.java:23)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser._reportCsvMappingError(CsvParser.java:1210)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser._handleExtraColumn(CsvParser.java:965)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser._handleNextEntry(CsvParser.java:826)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser.nextToken(CsvParser.java:580)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeUsingPropertyBased(BeanDeserializer.java:418)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1266)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:325)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.nextValue(MappingIterator.java:277)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.next(MappingIterator.java:192)
    ... 2 more
```

Is there any solution to ignore unwanted columns in csv?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found solution:

```
csvMapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.IGNORE_TRAILING_UNMAPPABLE)
```

Comment: `.enable(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN)` helped me with similar issues when trying to write from a class that had more fields than the schema I was using

Comment: As the constant name already states this would ignore only **trailing** columns. But unknown columns can appear at any position. `csvMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);` works for me using jackson-csv 2.11.4. Please verify if your solution is correct.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
csvMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Introduction**

For the sake of comprehensibility, here is a simple (Java) example that:

1. read a CSV-file from an InputStream (`jackson-dataformat-csv`
   dependency)
2. map its content to a list of objects (`jackson-core` dependency)

**CSV file content**

Let be `data.csv` a CSV file with the following data:

```
a;b;c
1;2;0.5
3;4;
```

**Java Class Data with a missing attributes**

The class `MyModel` represents a data class with the following attributes:

```
private Long a;
private Integer b;
```

Note the attribute `c` is missing, hence the parser will have to ignore it.

**Read the CSV content and map into a list of objects**

So the `CsvMapper` can be coupled with the Jackson object mapper to read records from a CSV file to a list of objects, the whole in a convenient method:

```
<U> List<U> mapRecordsToObjects(InputStream inputStream, Class<U> encodingType) {
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema bootstrapSchema = CsvSchema.emptySchema() //
                                         .withHeader() //
                                         .withColumnSeparator(";");
    ObjectReader reader = csvMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) //
                                   .readerFor(encodingType) //
                                   .with(bootstrapSchema);
    MappingIterator<U> iterator;
    try {
        iterator = reader.readValues(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("could not access file [%s]", this.source), e);
    }
    List<U> results = new ArrayList<>();
    iterator.forEachRemaining(results::add);
    return results;
}
```

Finally, let's call this method:

```
List<MyModel> result = mapRecordsToObjects(fileInputStream, MyModel.class);
```

In order to read the file, you will just need to initialise the InputStream.

**Deserialization feature**

In the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html), the class `DeserializationFeature` has the following description:

> Enumeration that defines simple on/off features that affect the way
>   Java objects are deserialized from JSON

In this enumeration class, there are many feature with a default state (sometimes per default enabled, sometimes disabled). The feature `FAIL_ON_UNKOWN_PROPERTIES` is *disable* per default can can be enabled as shown in the example. In its description, one can read:

> Feature that determines whether encountering of unknown properties
>   (ones that do not map to a property, and there is no "any setter" or
>   handler that can handle it) should result in a failure (by throwing a
>   {@link JsonMappingException}) or not.

Comment: Just on a side note, there is a also `List<T> MappingIterator#readAll()`, so you could'have amended `results::add` and simply write `List<U> results = iterator.readAll()`. Not sure if there are any complications, though.